# 12.04 won't recognize my CD/DVD Drive

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd

CD/DVD drive is an IDE slave device, and my hard drive is the IDE master device.
The hard drive is located at `/dev/sda1`, but `dev/sda2` can't be mounted. (I can't use `-t auto`
and I don't know what the file system in use is.

I've tried using said disc drive with filled and empty discs, but I can't mount `/dev/sda2/`. at all.

If anyone could help, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your main Hard disk drive is /dev/sda.  The partitions on that drive are numbered starting with sda, such as sda1, sda2, etc.

The CD/DVD drive is totally separate, with a name such as /dev/sr0.  It is usually mounted automatically in the /media directory when a disk is present, in a directory matching the name of the Disk.  On my system, the type is iso9660.